# Body Is Returning 400, But Postman Returns 200 OK

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I'm working on Spring Boot Project. My code:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createTask(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String description, @RequestParam String responsible_name) {

        return checkAuthorizationAndReturnResult(request, "ROLE_ADMIN",
                () -> {

                    try {

                        adminService.createTask(SCHEME_NAME, description, responsible_name);

                        return "Task Assigned Successfully To " + responsible_name;
                    }
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                        return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                        return new ResponseEntity<>("User Didn't Signed In Telegram Yet", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

When in postman i put a username that does not exist, postman returns in body:

```
{
    "headers": {},
    "body": "Username Does Not Exist",
    "statusCode": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "statusCodeValue": 400
}
```

But also returns 200 OK in its Status. How do i fix it, so it will return 400 also, like the body?

Tried everything possible, but can't find proper answer

Comment: Can you add checkAuthorizationAndReturnResult method?